# Compile Allegro 5.0.8 - static link (Code::Blocks 12.11, MinGW 4.7.1, Windows 7)

Tags: c++, mingw, codeblocks, allegro, allegro5

After installing Code::Blocks 12.11 (with MinGW 4.7.1 in distributive) on Windows 7 I try to compile simple Allegro 5 example. The only (official?) tutorial (a bit old) about it:
http://wiki.allegro.cc/index.php?title=Allegro_5_Tutorial
http://wiki.allegro.cc/index.php?title=Windows_Vista,_Code::Blocks_10.05_and_Allegro_5

## Question 1:

I've found allegro-5.0.8-mingw-4.5.0.7z. Is there a version for MinGW 4.7.1?

## Question 2:

Error:
mingw32-g++.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '-static-libstdc++'

## Question 3:

If I remove linking option -static-libstdc++, another error occurs:
c:/program files (x86)/codeblocks/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgcc_eh

## Question 4:

Is liballegro-5.0.8-monolith-static-mt.a a single replacement for all allegro .a files? Does it contain extern mingw .a dependencies, too? "Gameplay" of finding all these 30 .a files and configuring the right order is something horrible. It reminds anti-pattern http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_coupling :)

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: I'm proud to be the only person in the universe with a such dump issue. :) Nobody compile Allegro 5 on MinGW?